# Azure Owner Role cannot create Resource Group

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-resource-group

I am assigned an owner role in my Employer's Azure subscription. He was able to create resource groups, but I can't. We're both wondering why since I was already assigned as Owner, the highest role aside from subscription level.

When I try the `az group create --name myGroup -l southeastasia` command, its response is

```
The client 'live.com#<myAccount>@outlook.com' with object id '<object ID>'
does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/
resourcegroups/write' over scope '/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourcegroups/<myGroup>'.
```

Edit: I have no subscription level resources
[image: Azure Resources]

Comment: Hi, if you use this account to login Azure Portal, could you create a resource group. Could you see subscriptions in Portal?

Comment: I can see the Subscriptions blade in the portal but I'm unauthorized

Comment: I suggest you could re-assign `Owner` role with your employer's account. If possible, could you show error screenshot.

Comment: Also, if possible, you could create a sp to create resource group and resources. See my answer.

Comment: You should see your subscription like this https://imgur.com/a/6XKEV

Comment: You should give `Owner` role on subscription level, see my updated answer.

Comment: sorry, we haven't tried it yet, I'm still waiting to tell my employer about this

Comment: Please let me know if you need more future help :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have multiple subscriptions in your tenant? If yes, you should set it.

```
##list subscription
az account list --output table

##change the active subscription
az account set --subscription "My Demos"
```

If you only have a subscription, I suggest you could create a sp, then use the sp to create a new resource group. See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest).

Update:

You should give `Owner` role on subscription level, according to your screenshot, you give `Owner` role on resource group role, you only create resources in the resource group. You also could not create new resource group. You should give `Owner` role to your subscription,like below:

[image]

Comment: I don't own the subscription, it's my employer's. I'll ask him to give me ownership on that level but he may hesitate if that will allow me to access all. Can he still limit what I can do in the account even when my ownership is on subscription level?

Comment: @JohnStephen.19 What resources you want to create? 1. You could let your employer create resource group firstly, then you could create resources inside it. You no need create resource group.

Comment: @JohnStephen.19  Second solution you could create custom role to manage subscription. See this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-custom-roles

Comment: my boss accepted the second solution, but we haven't done it yet. I believe he doesn't have the time to do this, if only he can give me the authorization to create custom roles and assign it first. Anyway, thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This issue is more likely to happen in newer subscriptions and usually happens if a certain resource type has never been created before in that subscription.

Subscription admins often fix this issue by granting resource group owners contributor rights on the subscription level which contradicts with their strategy of isolating access down to the level of resource group level not the subscription level.

For root cause and quick resolution, refer "[Common problem when using Azure resource groups & RBAC"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azure4fun/2016/10/20/common-problem-when-using-azure-resource-groups-rbac/).

Comment: Useful blog post link in answer which shows how granting Contributor at subscription level is overkill / not necessary

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error clearly says you dont have rights over the scope, so you are either owner of the wrong sub or you have a role that specifically restricts that.

Comment: that scope is not even created yet, I'm creating that resource group so that scope won't be authorized to me in advance

Comment: subscription is the scope